# arbitrary number of arguments in a python function

Tags: python

I'd like to learn how to pass an arbitrary number of args in a python function, so I wrote a simple sum function in a recursive way as follows:

```
def mySum(*args):
  if len(args) == 1:
    return args[0]
  else:
    return args[-1] + mySum(args[:-1])
```

but when I tested `mySum(3, 4)`, I got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Does anyone have an idea about this and gimme some clue to correct it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This line:

```
return args[-1] + mySum(args[:-1])
```

`args[:-1]` returns a slice of the arguments tuple. I assume your goal is to recursively call your function using that slice of the arguments. Unfortunately, your current code simply calls your function using a single object - the slice itself.

What you want to do instead is to call with those args unrolled.

```
return args[-1] + mySum(*args[:-1])
                        ^---- note the asterisk
```

This technique is called "[unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)," and the asterisk is sometimes (informally) called the "splat" operator.

Comment: `splat` (the term) isn't as commonly used as I think it ought to be.  Some call it the "star" operator, others just the "unpacking" operator...  I suppose it has many names.

Comment: @mgilson: too bad `itertools.starmap` wasn't named `itertools.splatmap`, :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do it recursively:

```py
def mySum(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum = sum + i
    return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

`args[:-1]` is a tuple, so the nested call is actually `mySum((4,))`, and the nested return of `args[0]` returns a tuple.  So you end up with the last line being reduced to `return 3 + (4,)`.  To fix this you need to expand the tuple when calling mySum by changing the last line to `return args[-1] + mySum(*args[:-1])`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `args[:-1]` is a tuple, so `mySum(args[:-1])` is being called with the `args` being a tuple *containing* another tuple as the first argument. You want to call the function `mySum` with `args[:-1]` expanded to the arguments however, which you can do with

```
mySum(*args[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The arbitrary arguments are passed as tuple (with one asterisk*) to the function, (you can change it to a list as shown in the code) and calculate the sum of its elements, by coding yourself using a for loop; if don't want to use the sum() method of python.

```
def summing(*arg):
    li = list(*arg)
    x = 0
    for i in range((len(li)-1)):
        x = li[i]+x

    return x

#creating a list and pass it as arbitrary argument to the function
#to colculate the sum of it's elements

li = [4, 5 ,3, 24, 6, 67, 1]
print summing(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option1:

```
def mySum(*args):
    return sum(args)

mySum(1,2,3) # 6
mySum(1,2) # 3
```

Option 2:

```
mySum2 = lambda *args: sum(args)
mySum2(1,2,3) # 6
mySum2(1,2) # 3
```