# How can I get multiple sets of coordinates as arguments for a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function, `pixel`, that plots a pixel at a certain point in a window. For example, `pixel(10, 10)` will plot a pixel at the point (10, 10).

In a new function `pixels`, I would like it to be executable by typing something like `pixels((10, 10), (11, 11), ...)`, and it would use the `pixel` function the necessary amount of times to plot the pixels at the listed coordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arbitrary number of arguments in a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125218/arbitrary-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pixel(x, y):
    print(f"drawing pixel at ({x}, {y})")

def pixels(*args):
    for arg in args:
        assert isinstance(arg, tuple)
        pixel(*arg)

pixels((10, 10), (20, 20), (34, 66))
```

Output:

```
drawing pixel at (10, 10)
drawing pixel at (20, 20)
drawing pixel at (34, 66)
```

You may be better off asserting all arguments are tuples before passing any of them on to `pixel`. It would require two for-loops in series, or using `all`, but at least then you would only draw any pixels if all arguments are actually tuples.